# Increasing Binary field length

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a populated column of type binary(24).  I want to increase this field length to binary(32).  This part's easy enough.  The problem I'm running into is when I try to query the table based on that field's previous value.  (We were using a hashbytes function).

So BEFORE the field length increase, I could just use:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = HASHBYTES('md5', 'value')
```

AFTER the field length increase, this query returns nothing.  How would I change the query to return the appropriate value?  What can I add on to the end of the binary in order for it to be recognized?

Thanks!

Edit: I've apparently done something ELSE wrong, as this works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (test binary(24) null)
insert into #test (test) values (hashbytes('md5', 'test'))
select * from #test
ALTER TABLE #test ALTER COLUMN test binary(32) null
select * from #test where test = hashbytes('md5', 'test')

drop table #test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use CONVERT in the WHERE to turn it back into binary(24) ?

[CONVERT binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167253/how-to-convert-binary-string-back-to-byte-in-csharp-hex-number-created-by-sql-s)

Comment: That does work in my test (edited above), so I must have done something else wrong.  :/  Thanks.